# Help with plotting the following

Tags: pgfplots

Bellow is the following code that I currently have, I am just struggling to replicate the graph as accurately as I would like. The actual functions for the graphs are quite complex so i am just trying to replicate with some trig functions etc.

Here is what what I am trying to achieve..
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    ymax=1,ymin=0, ylabel=$\omega$, 
    xmin=-pi, xlabel=$\beta_p$
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:pi, blue, thick] {0.3*sin(35*x-50)+0.7};
    \addplot[domain=-pi:pi, blue, dashed] {sin(10*x-35)+1};
    \addplot[domain=-pi:0,blue,thick] {0.02*(x+3)^2+0.085};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With only `tikz`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=gray!50] (-5,0) rectangle (5,1);
  \draw (-5,1) -- (5,1);
  \fill[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=gray!50] (-5,7) rectangle (5,8);
  \draw (-5,7) -- (5,7) (-5,8) -- (5,8);
  \draw[-latex,thick] (-5,0) -- (5.5,0)node[pos=1,anchor=west]{$\beta_p$}
                                     node[pos=1,below,anchor=north east]{$+\pi$};
  \draw[-latex,thick] (0,0)node[below]{0} -- (0,8)node[pos=1,above]{$\omega$};  
  \draw[dashed] (5,0) -- (5,8);
  \node[font=\bfseries] at (-3,0.5) {LH Gap};
  \node[font=\bfseries] at (3,7.5) {RH Gap};
  %% curves
  \draw[dashed,gray] (-5,1) to[out = 0, in = 180] (5,7);
  \draw[dashed,gray] (-5,1) to[out = 0, in = 250] (0,8);
  \draw[dashed,gray] (0,0) -- (2,4) to[out = 65, in = 180] (5,7);
  \draw[thick,blue] (-5,1) to[out = 0, in = 240] (0,3);
  \node[circle, inner sep=2pt,fill=blue] at (0,3){};
  \node[circle, inner sep=2pt,fill=blue] at (0,5){};
  \draw[thick,blue] (0,5) to[out = 10, in = 180] (3.5,7) -- (5,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats great, I can amend to suit, the functions are great. Thanks kumar

Comment: @BenQuinton You are welcome. Adjust `in` and `out` angles suitably.

Answer (score 4):

Done with the `mfpic` package, a (La)TeX interface to MetaPost.

Since the picture borders' coordinates `\xmin`, `\xmax`, `\ymin`, `\ymax` take their values in the four arguments of the `mfpic` environment, I've tried to parameterize the picture as much as possible in function of them. Hence the relative length of the code.

Key parameters here are the x-coordinate of the upper left summit G of the ‘‘LH Gap’’, that is to say `\xmin`, the common height `barheight` of these gaps, which is also the second coordinate of G, and the y-coordinate `\ymax` of the picture's upper-right corner.

It may be fun to play with those three parameters and see how the picture fares (without warranty :-)). Below I gave those parameters the values given in Harish Kumar's tikz coding.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[metapost, mplabels, truebbox]{mfpic}
    \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
    \mfpverbtex{%&latex
        \documentclass{scrartcl}
        \begin{document}}
\opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[1]{-5}{6}{0}{8}
    \setmfnumeric{barheight}{1}
    \setmfpair{G}{(\xmin, barheight)} % Upper left summit of "LH Gap"
    \setmfpair{C}{(- xpart G, \ymax - barheight)} % Lower right summit of "RH Gap"
    \hatchcolor[gray]{.8}
    \lhatch\rect{G, (xpart C, \ymin)}
    \lines{G, (xpart C, ypart G)}
    \lhatch\rect{(xpart G, \ymax), C}
    \lines{(xpart G, ypart C), C}
    \lines{(xpart G, \ymax), (xpart C, \ymax)}
    \drawcolor[gray]{.6}
    \dashed\mfobj{origin{dir 60} --- (.4xpart C, .6ypart C) .. C{right}}
    \dashed\mfobj{G{right} .. C{right}}
    \dashed\mfobj{G{right} .. (0, \ymax){dir 70}}
    \setmfarray{path}{P}{%
        G{right} ... (0, 3/7ypart C){dir 60}, 
        (0, 5/7ypart C){dir 10} .. (3.5/5xpart C, ypart C) --- C{right}}
    \drawcolor{blue}
    \mfobj{P1}\mfobj{P2}
    \pointcolor{blue}
    \point[3bp]{point 1 of P1}
    \point[3bp]{point 0 of P2}
    \drawcolor{black}
    \doaxes{xy}
    \dashed\lines{(xpart C, 0), (xpart C, \ymax)}
    \tlpointsep{3bp}
    \tlabels{[tc]{origin}{$O$} [cl]{(\xmax, 0)}{$\beta_p$} 
        [tc]{(xpart C, 0)}{$+\pi$} [bc]{(0, \ymax)}{$\omega$}
        [cc]{(.5xpart C, .5(ypart C + \ymax))}{\textbf{RH Gap}}
        [cc]{(.5xpart G, .5(ypart G + \ymin))}{\textbf{LH Gap}}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

The result is thus more or less the same, when the program is executed with (PDF)LaTeX, then with MetaPost and then again with (PDF)LaTeX:

[image]